# How to make a WebView Load fast And adding a Progress bar to it

Tags: android

I am making a simple application in which I have put a webview, but the page is loading very slow(tried with many websites) and also I want to add a progress bar so it should show that the page is loading.
Here is the code I am using for webview but I have no idea how to get progress bar on it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new webCont());

    wv.loadUrl(" http://www.abc.com" ); 
}
 class webCont extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a progress bar. Display the same. You customize the below to suit your needs. To load faster it depends on the connection speed.

Override `onPageFinished` and set the visibility to gone in webcount

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:id="@+id/wv"/>
    <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Snaps

Without scrolling you don't see entire page

[image]

With scrolling right

[image]

Comment: Ok,Thank you that worked. if the website is not responsive it is giving a fixed display no scrolling, How to add scroll??

Comment: @Karma5 as i said it depends on the speed of internet connection. it is still loading and takes time to render. try different urls just for testing

Comment: I am asking question about non responsive website not speed of website. It is giving a fixed display i cannot move the page left or right

Comment: @Karma5 it will be scrollable. it does scroll for me.

Comment: @Karma5 it does scroll. i don't why it does not for you

Answer (score 3):

Set webview on `WebChromeClient()` and try this code

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);  
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");  

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            if (progress < 100) {
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            if (progress == 100) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl(" http://www.abc.com" ); 
                //Show Progress layout
                showProgressLayout();

        wv.setWebViewClient(new webCont());

}
 class webCont extends WebViewClient
{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;

   @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                //Hide Progress bar.

                hideProgressLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                //If any error comes this method will handle for webview.

                hideProgressLayout();

                if (view.canGoBack()) {
                    view.goBack();
                }

                You can write your own Dialog or Toast message if you want to show error message
            }
}
```

Comment: @Karma5 the speed still depends on the speed of your internet connection whether its wifi or mobile data. it also depends on the site you are loading. a website with lots of images will load slower than the one with just text data