# Activity slow load when there is a webView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, kotlin, android-webview

I have an activity that contains a button, the button initiates an intent to open another activity and sets some extra data, e.g.:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ViewOnline::class.java)
intent.putExtra(URL_TO_SEND_KEY, url)
this.startActivity(intent)
```

In the activity that is launched, it simply contains a webView and nothing else. In onCreate I have:

```
webView.webViewClient = webViewClient

webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true

val url = intent.extras.get(URL_TO_SEND_KEY) as String?
if (url != null) {
    webView.loadUrl(url)
}
```

This all works fine, but, when launching the activity from pressing the button it takes ~5 seconds before the new activity is displayed and I can't work out what it's doing and why it takes so long. Any ideas?

UPDATE: It appears to only be an issue in the emulator. Real device doesn't seem to experience the same problem.

Here is the full class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.resources_online.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.indeterminateProgressDialog

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
class ViewResourcesOnline : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.resources_online)

        setupAdView()

        loadBannerAd()

        val loadingDialogue = indeterminateProgressDialog("Loading...")

        val webViewClient: WebViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                loadingDialogue.dismiss()
            }

            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                loadingDialogue.show()
            }
        }

        button_back_resources_online.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView_resources_online.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        }
        else {
            webView_resources_online.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
        }

        webView_resources_online.webViewClient = webViewClient

        webView_resources_online.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView_resources_online.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView_resources_online.settings.useWideViewPort = true

        val url = intent.extras.get(RESOURCES_KEY) as String?

        when {
            (url != null) -> {
                webView_resources_online.loadUrl(url)
            }
            else -> {
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupAdView() {
        adView_resources_online.adListener = object: AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                adView_resources_online.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode : Int) {
                adView_resources_online.visibility = View.GONE
            }

        }
    }

    private fun loadBannerAd() {
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.adMobAppId))

        if (!inAppPurchase) {
            adView_resources_online.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @FlatDog have you tried setting the heap size in the manifest? 
http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/th...lication-memory-cache-size.33760/#post-197730
Also One more link i got while seraching on the improving webview performance : - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282519/how-to-make-a-webview-load-fast-and-adding-a-progress-bar-to-it

Comment: Could u post the entire class, and it could be better Web view loadurl should be called in onresume method instead of oncreate

Comment: I updated the post with the entire class. It doesn't seem to be any different moving webView loadURL from onResume.

Comment: @FlatDog Was you solve this problem?

Comment: @andreich, no, just appears to be normal slowness of simulator.