# Android - only load part of website in webview

Tags: android, performance, webview

So in my app, I'm using a `WebView` which has to frequently load websites pretty fast. These websites contain a lot of unnecessary stuff which does not have to be loaded for my app to work.

Is there a way to not load certain areas of a website? Or are there some tricks to make webviews load faster?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no way to load certain parts of a website unless you make some tweaks on the website itself,for the performance trick you might wanna check this thread ,

[How to make a WebView Load fast And adding a Progress bar to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282519/how-to-make-a-webview-load-fast-and-adding-a-progress-bar-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

It will always depend on the website that is being loaded. 
But besides that you can try some of these approaches:

**Set higher render priority (deprecated from API 18+):**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
     webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
}
```

**Enable/disable hardware acceleration:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

**Enable cache:**

```
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webview.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
```

**Enable database:**

```
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true)
```

**Enable DOM storage:**

```
 webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Shouldn't I set the render priority to low instead of high?

Comment: If you want performance it should be HIGH, but it is deprecated ;)

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll definitely try them out and let you know if it helped.